# How does keras obtain a floating point value for loss from a vector of loss values?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training an ML model in Tensorflow 1.15 using a custom training loop and I want to print out the loss, however, it is a vector with a dimension equal to the batch size. What does Keras do when you call `model.fit()` to print the loss as a float? Does it reduce it to the mean of the vector, or perhaps it performs some other reduction?

The reason I am asking is that I want to make sure the loss I am logging is consistent throughout my models and others did not require a custom training loop.

Comment: " What does Keras do when you call model.fit() to print the loss?"  Did you check the source code?

Comment: I did, but unfortunately, I do not think that output is part of the fit method, though perhaps I am simply missing it. My hope is that someone actually knows and can help me out, rather than me having to muddle through the source code for an extended period of time.

Comment: you can determine anything in custom training loop. Normally there should be a mean

Comment: @Andrey That's what I was wondering if Keras does a mean reduction or something else.  From your answer sounds like it is using the mean of the errors. By any chance do you happen to know where that calculation is performed in the code?